# Argument of type T<Y> is not assignable to parameter of type T<X> where Y is a subclass of X

Tags: typescript, typeerror

It is my goal to have a parent class define events, and have the subclass fire events for them, but the type passed in those events will depend on the subclass, but it will be of some base class. It is hard to put in words, so here is my simplified TypeScript code that still produces the error:

```js
// The type 'T' not being passed in a function argument fixes it.
type Listener<T> = (e: T) => any
class EventEmitter<T> {
  private listeners: Listener<T>[] = []
  fire(data: T): void {}
}
class Node {
  constructor(readonly graph: Graph<Node>, readonly data: string) {}
}
// Error: Property 'file' is missing in type 'Node' but required in type 'FileNode'.
class FileNode extends Node {
  // Error: Type 'Graph<FileNode>' is not assignable to type 'Graph<Node>'.
  constructor(readonly graph: Graph<FileNode>, readonly file: string, data: string) {
    // Error: Argument of type 'Graph<FileNode>' is not assignable to
    // parameter of type 'Graph<Node>'.
    super(graph, data)
  }
}
abstract class Provider<T extends Node> {
  _onDidCreate = new EventEmitter<T>()
  abstract setup(graph: Graph<T>): void
}
class Graph<T extends Node> {
  // Replacing 'T' for 'any' here makes it work too,
  // but that is obviously not a proper fix.
  constructor(readonly provider: Provider<T>) {}
}
```

And I planned to use it like this for example:

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode"
// Error: Type 'FileNode' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.
export class VSCodeProvider extends Provider<FileNode> {
  constructor(readonly root: string) {
    super()
  }
  setup(graph: Graph<FileNode>) {
    const watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(this.root)
    watcher.onDidCreate((fileUri: vscode.Uri) => {
      this._onDidCreate.fire(new FileNode(graph, fileUri.fsPath, "...data..."))
    })
  }
}
```

**How can I properly fix these type errors?** Part of me feels like these errors point to just a bad design in general, so if anybody instead has suggestions how to just workaround these errors by having a better structure, that is even better.

Each node contains data that determines how the graph should be build, e.g. which links should be made, but it can only do so given knowledge of the graph as a whole, hence needing access to the graph. I could swap this around and pass a node to the graph, but a node needs less information from a graph, then a graph would need from a node to figure things out, so that seemed bad design. The code seems to suffer from a highly coupled provider/graph and node/graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for type errors turned out to be something I really should have known. [Arguments in functions following contravariant subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)):

> On the other hand, "function from Animal to String" is a subtype of "function from Cat to String" because the function type constructor is contravariant in the parameter type. Here the subtyping relation of the simple types is reversed for the complex types.

So given the Animal/Cat example used in the quote, my problem could be simplified to:

```js
class Animal { animal = 1 }
class Cat extends Animal { cat = 1 }
class AnimalFunc<T extends Animal> {
  func: (arg: T) => void
}
class AnimalHandler {
  constructor(func: AnimalFunc<Animal>) {}
}
class CatHandler extends AnimalHandler {
  constructor(func: AnimalFunc<Cat>) {
    // Type 'T' is used contravariant, hence the error:
    // Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'Cat'.
    super(func)
  }
}
```

Or simplified even further by passing function immediately:

```js
class Animal { animal = 1 }
class Cat extends Animal { cat = 1 }
class AnimalHandler {
  constructor(func: (arg: Animal) => void) {}
}
class CatHandler extends AnimalHandler {
  constructor(func: (arg: Cat) => void) {
    // Type 'T' is used contravariant, hence the error:
    // Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'Cat'.
    super(func)
  }
}
```

The solution was to change `Graph` to no longer have a provider as a property, but have it passed to it only where needed as a function argument. Since the provider is only needed by the graph to setup event callbacks, providing it as an argument suffices. For example, `Graph` becomes:

```js
class Graph<T extends Node> {
  provide(provider: Provider<T>) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface they both implement.
Then you use the interface as the handle.

```js
export interface INode{}

export class Node implements INode {...}
export class FileNode implements IProvider {...}

export class VSCodeProvider extends Provider<INode> {...}
```

Or just check the existing classes if they have a common interface.